# Why IE can't read the CSS Stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I have some page: http://kaduli.com.br/index_pop.asp and works fine on Chrome, and Firefox. (the form wont work)

PS: The form is incomplete! Its not my problem.

But on IE the page don't load inside the lightbox.

If we open the page out of lightbox, the page load the css, but if you press `F12` for the developer tools on IE, you cant find the CSS!

The page inside the lightbox is: http://www.kaduli.com.br/home_box.html

As you can see, the "font" is not the same at Chrome and Firefox.

What is wrong with the page?

Comment: where's the form that makes the lightbox function? index_pop.asp resolves to index

Comment: the lightbox function is on index_pop.asp - i use Lightbox Evolution, and i call this way: `$.lightbox("home_box.html?lightbox[modal]=true&lightbox[width]=706&lightbox[height]=335");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the iframe mode instead of inline HTML mode if you're showing a complete HTML file with its own CSS styles in the lightbox.

So browsing the [Lightbox Evolution examples](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-lightbox-evolution/full_screen_preview/115655), that would be `?lightbox[iframe]=true&lightbox[width]=706&lightbox[height]=335`.

Comment: F**k yeah! This works inside lightbox on IE, BUT, why the page can't read the css? As i said before, if you open the developers tool on IE, you cant find the CSS

Comment: @Preston: The css **does** show now that the page is loaded as an iframe (Developer Tools, CSS tab, last two elements in the list). The styles were probably not parsed by IE at all when the link element was placed inline.

Comment: But my css link is on the same page. If you open on Firefox and Chrome, you can see the CSS tab. I use Firebug on firefox and Chrome and works fine...

Comment: Yup, with index_pop.asp open, `kaduli.com.br/css/home.css` is shown in Firebug in the dropdown menu on the CSS tab, and `[/home_box.html] http://kaduli.com.br/css/home.css` is shown in IE9 Developer Tools in the dropdown menu on the CSS tab, along with `[/home_box.html] http://fonts.googleapis.com/css`. Not the same for you, or do I miss your point?

Comment: With inline I meant that the whole external HTML file home_box.html was loaded and placed in the body section on the page index_pop.asp when using the inline mode. Which resulted in invalid code (html, head, body etc. in the parent page's body). Firefox handled this situation quite well, loading the CSS file etc., but IE didn't – and indeed shouldn't have to.

Comment: No, its not the same. I use IE8, and i cant found ` http://kaduli.com.br/css/home.css` under the CSS Tab. You can see here: http://postimage.org/image/57gg3ek19/

Comment: Oh, I see. In IE9, styles from iframe pages are shown as well (no matter whether the browser mode is IE9, IE8 or IE7), with brackets around their names: http://postimage.org/image/4pz4mfn85/. Not much we can do about that, I guess. Except upgrade to IE9. =)

Comment: yeah.. but i dont know why the google font in IE, is not applied on `h2`: `Cadastre-se hoje!` i have used the `PT Narrow Sans`..

Comment: Hmm, again works here in IE9... You might want to try referencing the Google CSS file directly on the page, like home.css, instead of importing it. If that doesn't work, perhaps a new SO question is in order.

Comment: yeah.. i try this.. thaks for help !